# Why does $tr \ e^{-\frac{i}{h}\hat{H}t}= \int d^nr \left< \textbf{r}| e^{-\frac{i}{h}\hat{H}t} | \textbf{r} \right>$ hold?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, propagator

I would like to consider the trace of the time evolution operator $e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}t}$

Apparently in single-particle quantum mechanics is can be represented as

$$ tr \ e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}t}= \int d^nr \left< \textbf{r}| e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}t} | \textbf{r} \right>= \int d^nr K(\textbf{r},\textbf{r},t)
$$

The second equality follows from the definition of a propagator but I cannot see how first equality holds.

Comment: That's, um, the *definition* of a trace.

Comment: Maybe then I cannot see the reasoning behind the definition

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Its clear to me only in the discrete case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In finite-dimensional space, given an orthonormal basis $\lvert e_i \rangle$, the trace is

$$ \mathrm{Tr}(A) := \sum_i \langle e_i \rvert A \lvert e_i \rangle $$

Informally, in infinite-dimensional spaces, the sum is replaced by an integral.

Formally, you would have to check whether the operator is [trace class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class), and see that the integral reproduces the convergent sum over the countable basis of our separable Hilbert space, but luckily, the idea of integrating (=infinitely summing) over the uncountable position "basis" produces the correct result (if the operator is nice), so physicists seldomly bother with that.

Comment: It is very far from obvious. If $e^{-\tau H}$ is compact, trace class, **positive** (it obviously holds if $H$ is self-adjoint), and admits a $(x,y)$-*continuous* kernel $K(t,x,y)$ representing it, then the trace can be computed as expected $tr(e^{-\tau H})= \int K(x,x) dx$ as consequence of **Mercher's** theorem. Then an analytic continuation $\tau \to i t$ should extend the result the real time case...